# Criptografar URL e reduzir tamanho da criptografia PHP

Tags: php, base64

Eu estou fazendo um sisteminha básico aonde eu passe informações como, titulo, url video, imagem... estou criando desta forma por que não quero utilizar banco de dados.

quando eu vou fazer essa criptografia

$mp4 = base64($link);

ele criptografa essa url

https://servidor:8080/f/l/d/video-dub.mp4

resultado

```
aHR0cHM6Ly9zZXJ2aWRvcjo4MDgwL2YvbC9kL3ZpZGVvLWR1Yi5tcDQ=
```

queria reduzir isso ficar mais o menos desse tamanho

```
aHR0cHM6Ly9zZX
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua pergunta contêm alguns erros. Primeiro que base64 não é uma função criptográfica, ele apenas codifica o seu conteudo em 64 caracteres, não há necessariamente uma redução de tamanho. Segundo como é apenas uma codificação não há como diminuir seu tamanho e continuar com seu conteudo original. Você deve procurar algo para compactar como GZip ou LZstrig(js).